# Cant install "saas-rails" gem on windows 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, window, sass

I installed Rails using http://railsinstaller.org/ on my windows 7 machine.
I had problem with mysql2 gem, but it have been solved by downloading mysql C connector and using custom key:

```
C:\Users\lenovo>gem install mysql2 -- --with-mysql-dir=c:\mysql-connector-c-6.1.
3-win32
```

**For now I am stuck with this error:**

```
C:\Dropbox\xcams\ror>ruby script\rails
←[31mCould not find gem 'sass-rails (~> 3.2.3) x86-mingw32' in the gems availabl
e on this machine.←[0m
←[33mRun `bundle install` to install missing gems.←[0m
```

If I reinstall gem no errors:

```
C:\Dropbox\xcams\ror>gem install "sass-rails"
Successfully installed sass-rails-4.0.1
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for sass-rails-4.0.1...
Installing RDoc documentation for sass-rails-4.0.1...
```

Check that gem in the list:

```
C:\Dropbox\xcams\ror>gem list | findstr sass
sass (3.2.13)
sass-rails (4.0.1)
```

Try to start. Same error again:

```
C:\Dropbox\xcams\ror>ruby script\rails
←[31mCould not find gem 'sass-rails (~> 3.2.3) x86-mingw32' in the gems availabl
e on this machine.←[0m
←[33mRun `bundle install` to install missing gems.←[0m
```

How properly install this gem on winodws?
My environment:

```
C:\Users\lenovo>ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p484 (2013-11-22) [i386-mingw32]

C:\Users\lenovo>gem -v
1.8.28

C:\Users\lenovo>rails -v
Rails 4.0.2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was with my IDE (Intellij Idea 13)
When I generate RoR app from console all works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Notice the different versions. Try to enforce the version you have installed on the Gemfile:

```
  `gem "sass-rails", "4.0.1"`
```